# How to set an atribute in html with thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have a spring application that gets me a city with an attribute of a model. In html code I have a  with many . So, I want to know how I could set an option to be selected if option value is equal with atribute value from model.

```
<select class="form-control" id="county" required="required">
    <option>Roma</option>
    <option>Milano</option>
    <option>Paris</option>
    <option>London</option>
    <option selected="selected">Bucharest</option>
</selected
```

And model attribute from spring application:

```
model.addAttribute("county", user.getCounty()); //which is "Bucharest" in this case
```

Answer (score 0):

Add th:value to select component

```
<select class="form-control" id="county" required="required" th:value="*{county}">
```

If you have an object bound to the form, use `th:field="*{county}"` instead